How to Implement Smooth 5-Second Rewind and Fast-Forward in Kivy Video Player with FFpyPlayer and KivyMD
I'm working on a custom video player using Kivy, KivyMD, and FFpyPlayer in Python. The player currently supports basic play, pause, and stop functions, but I'm aiming to add rewind and fast-forward buttons that will skip 5 seconds back or forward, as seen in most media players.
My goal is to implement buttons for:

Rewind by 5 seconds
Fast-forward by 5 seconds

I'm aware of potential timing and sync issues when adjusting the playhead position manually, so I'd like to understand the best way to ensure smooth functionality.
My current setup is:

Using Kivy Video as the primary component for video playback.
Leveraging FFpyPlayer for video rendering.
Utilizing KivyMD for UI styling and layout.

I attempted to update the playhead position using the seek() method in FFpyPlayer, adjusting it by 5 seconds forward or backward. However, this approach has led to issues with smoothness, as the video sometimes lags or stutters when seeking.
Below is a simplified version of my setup. The code includes buttons to rewind and fast-forward by 5 seconds. However, the buttons occasionally don't work as expected and sometimes jump to the beginning or end of the video rather than skipping by the desired amount.
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.video import Video
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRaisedButton
from kivymd.uix.slider import MDSlider
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen

KV = '''
MDScreen:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        Video:
            id: video
            source: 'videos/test.mp4'
            state: 'stop'
            allow_stretch: True

        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: '50dp'
            padding: '10dp'
            spacing: '10dp'

            MDRaisedButton:
                text: 'Play'
                on_release: app.play_pause_video()

            MDRaisedButton:
                text: 'Pause'
                on_release: app.play_pause_video()

            MDRaisedButton:
                text: 'Rewind 5s'
                on_release: app.rewind_5s()

            MDRaisedButton:
                text: 'Forward 5s'
                on_release: app.forward_5s()

            MDSlider:
                id: slider
                min: 0
                max: 100
                value: 0
                on_touch_up: app.on_slider_touch_up(*args)
'''

class VideoPlayerApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.screen = Builder.load_string(KV)
        self.video = self.screen.ids.video
        self.slider = self.screen.ids.slider

        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_slider, 1 / 30)
        return self.screen

    def play_pause_video(self):
        if self.video.state == 'play':
            self.video.state = 'pause'
        else:
            self.video.state = 'play'

    def rewind_5s(self):
        new_position = max(self.video.position - 5, 0)
        self.video.seek(new_position)

    def forward_5s(self):
        new_position = min(self.video.position + 5, self.video.duration)
        self.video.seek(new_position)

    def update_slider(self, dt):
        if self.video.duration > 0:
            self.slider.max = self.video.duration
            self.slider.value = self.video.position

    def on_slider_touch_up(self, instance, touch):
        if instance.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            self.video.seek(instance.value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    VideoPlayerApp().run()

The issues I've encountered are:

Timing Sync: The video does not always smoothly transition when seeking, resulting in some noticeable stutter or lag.

Button Responsiveness: The responsiveness of the rewind and fast-forward buttons is inconsistent, possibly due to limitations in the seek() method.

Jumping to Start/End: Sometimes when pressing the Rewind 5s or Forward 5s buttons, the video unexpectedly jumps to the very beginning or end instead of skipping by just 5 seconds.


My questions are:

Is there a more efficient approach in FFpyPlayer or Kivy to enhance the performance of the seek() function for smooth 5-second skips?

Are there any libraries, methods, or techniques that offer better control over video playback in Kivy, especially for implementing rewind and fast-forward features?



.seek method accepts values from 0 to 1 so you have to convert the seconds you want to skip to fit 0 to 1
you will then go ahead to use triggered clock to control slider updates to avoid bringing you back to same position whenever your forward or rewind
Github Source Code
"""
How to Implement Smooth 5-Second Rewind and Fast-Forward
in Kivy Video Player with FFpyPlayer and KivyMD
"""

from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivymd.app import MDApp

KV = '''
MDScreen:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        Video:
            id: video
            source: 'videos/test.mp4'
            state: 'stop'
            allow_stretch: True

        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: '50dp'
            padding: '10dp'
            spacing: '10dp'

            MDRaisedButton:
                text: 'Play'
                on_release: app.play_pause_video()

            MDRaisedButton:
                text: 'Pause'
                on_release: app.play_pause_video()

            MDRaisedButton:
                text: 'Rewind 5s'
                on_release: app.rewind_5s()

            MDRaisedButton:
                text: 'Forward 5s'
                on_release: app.forward_5s()

            MDSlider:
                id: slider
                min: 0
                max: 1
                value: 0
                on_touch_up: app.on_slider_touch_up(*args)
'''


class VideoPlayerApp(MDApp):
    _fwd_position = NumericProperty(0)
    _bwd_position = NumericProperty(0)
    screen = ObjectProperty()
    video = ObjectProperty()
    slider = ObjectProperty()
    clock = ObjectProperty()
    
    def build(self):
        self.screen = Builder.load_string(KV)
        self.video = self.screen.ids.video
        self.slider = self.screen.ids.slider

        self.clock = Clock.create_trigger(self.update_slider, 1 / 30)
        return self.screen

    def play_pause_video(self):
        if self.video.state == 'play':
            self.video.state = 'pause'
            self.clock.cancel()
        else:
            self.video.state = 'play'
            self.clock()

    def rewind_5s(self):
        self.clock.cancel()
        if self._bwd_position > self.video.position or self._bwd_position == 0:
            new_position = max(self.video.position - 5, 0)
            self._bwd_position = new_position
        else:
            self._bwd_position = new_position = self._bwd_position - 5
        duration = self.video.duration
        self.video.seek(new_position / duration)
        Clock.schedule_once(lambda _: self.clock(), 2)

    def forward_5s(self):
        self.clock.cancel()
        if self._fwd_position < self.video.position:
            new_position = min(self.video.position + 5, self.video.duration)
            self._fwd_position = new_position
        else:
            self._fwd_position = new_position = self._fwd_position + 5
        duration = self.video.duration
        self.video.seek(new_position / duration)
        Clock.schedule_once(lambda _: self.clock(), 2)

    def update_slider(self, _):
        duration = self.video.duration
        position = self.video.position
        self.slider.value = min(1, max(position / duration, 0))

    def on_slider_touch_up(self, instance, touch):
        self.clock.cancel()
        if instance.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            self.video.seek(instance.value)
        Clock.schedule_once(lambda _: self.clock(), 2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    VideoPlayerApp().run()


I believe the main problem in your code is that you are using the seek() method incorrectly. According to the documentation:

seek(percent, precise=True)
Change the position to a percentage (strictly, a proportion)

    of duration.

Parameters:

    percent: float or int

        Position to seek as a proportion of the total duration, must be between 0-1.
    precise: bool, defaults to True

        Precise seeking is slower, but seeks to exact requested percent.


So the percent must be a value between 0 and 1. You can calculate the correct percent by getting the video duration. Try adding to your KV:
    Video:
        id: video
        source: 'videos/test.mp4'
        state: 'stop'
        allow_stretch: True
        on_duration: app.get_duration()

and in your App add the method:
def get_duration(self, *args):
    # get duration, not available until video is loaded
    self.duration = self.video.duration

Then modify your rewind and forward methods to calculate a percentage:
def rewind_5s(self):
    new_position = max((self.video.position - 5)/self.duration, 0)
    self.video.seek(new_position)

def forward_5s(self):
    new_position = min((self.video.position + 5)/self.duration, 1)
    self.video.seek(new_position)


Optimize the Seek Method
Even though seek () is the common approach to get directly to the designated spot on the video; however, this may result in choppy playback if the underlying mechanism for the video is not well optimized for seeking. There are some recommendations in this respect:
Buffering and Caching: Add a buffer to the video player that is set to a certain number of frames before the current position. This can facilitate seeking and make the movement more seamless.
Use a Separate Thread: When there is a need to perform seeking, do so in a different thread so as not to block the primary UI thread. Clock.schedule_once function in Kivy is able to manage UI updates thanks to its ability of scheduling the updates without pauses in video playback.
Implement Smooth Seeking
Instead of jumping directly for fast forward and rewind, create a way of seeking that is smooth and transitions gradually:
from kivy.clock import Clock
class VideoPlayerApp(MDApp):
Existing methods…
def seek_video(self, delta):
Calculate new position
new_position = max(0, min(self.video.position + delta, self.video.duration))
self.video.seek(new_position)
def rewind_5s(self):
self.seek_video(-5)
def forward_5s(self):
self.seek_video(5)
3.Associate Responsiveness with Button Presses.
Make sure that the button responses are quite seamless in execution:
Typical Debounce Button Presses: This is the responsibility of the mechanic engineer as he/she will be compelled to add a gradual switch to avoid surge in the button presses.
def on_rewind_press(self):
if no self.is_seeking:
self.is_seeking = True self.rewind_5s() Clock .schedule_once( lambda dt: self.reset_seeking(), 0,5 )
def reset_seeking(self):
self.is_seeking = False
Ffplyayer Features.
Place a check on FFpy - Player documentation for feature pointers that may help handle video rendering in a better way :
Seek Precision: Some players have the option of seeking and controlling which specific parts of the video to seek (e.g. keyframe seeking vs timestamp seeking) thus ensure you get the ideal user practices for their specified needs.
Error Handling: Handle your seek calls with appropriate error handling measures so that you cover for any unexpected behavior.

Testing and Debugging

Log Seek Operations: However, to understand why the video does occasionally hop erratically, add logging around your seek calls to capture the current position before and after seeking.
def rewind_5s(self): what is the broadcast of cbc news on sirius radio p.118 new_position posture starting such discipline ccuneate.
new_position = max(self.video.position - 5, 0) cut footage to appropriate angle essentially unwiped so flip shot is never perfectly straight over the hand. THIS MEANS THEY WILL BE ABOUT 30 SECONDS LATE IN CUTTING THE FINAL Total SHOTPat SRI PRABHAKAR bhatt sharma rap known as Sri Prabhu animations Pritviraj lip synchronization. �cutewithravi@gmail.com 194 look grammar in a more casual and friendly tone. Look 36:6-38:53 Facebook five feeds ten pounds, silence.
print(f"Seeking from {self.video.position} to {new_position}") self.video.seek(new_position) def forward_5s(self): new_position = min(self.video.position + 5, self.video.duration) print(f"Seeking from {self.video.position} to {new_position}") tell people that its a programming space video, cut comes at 4:37 with the drones likely altering the position. They must be kept centered and as still as possible. self.video.seek(new_position)
Copy
Alternative Libraries
Nonetheless, if the issues still stick, you might want to try other libraries:
Gstreamer: US Intel 2006. v Justin timbers act and log in around an enormous spotlight. Curtis new tip more Collins to scan for Tanning Youtube Chris Evans community screening event mannequin shaped lights travel Hypershrink DOM visuals roaming throughout. It is a very powerful multimedia framework which might outperform the seeking and playback centered sections.
Conclusion
Following through those bullet points, targeting optimization to the largest performance bottlenecks moving part of seeking implementation, handling responsiveness of buttons considerably better and looking at other libraries if necessary means you can safely boost greatly the performance of Kivy video player. Testing and debugging with logging will also help in determining the specific issues and enhancing user experience.

Are you aware of our policy forbidding AI-generated content?
